# How to write reusable errors?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, throw

I have a function that evaluates an object, if its true, it pushes the object into an empty array if its false it needs to throw an error. How do I structure the Error so it's reusable, and can be overridden with some other message. Is it possible to not use the Try block?

```
const object1={
    title: "The Bridge",
    grade:  4.0,
    score: "Drama/Horrorr"
}

const object2={
    title:"Better Call Saul",
    score:7.0,
}
let shows=[];

function Add(param){
   if(param.hasOwnProperty("title") && 
      param.hasOwnProperty("score") &&
      param.hasOwnProperty("genre")) {
      shows.push(param);
      }
   else{
       throw "Object is missing a property !";
   }
   add(object1);
   add(object2);

   try{

   }
   catch(param){

   }

   Add(object1);
   Add(object2);
```

Comment: You can extend `Error` and build your own custom error classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using try/catch is the most standard approach in javascript. I would stick with that instead of trying to fight the tide.
throwing an Error object is also the standard object to throw

```
throw new Error('message')
```

or construct the error and add properties to it

```
const err = new Error('message')
err.code = 1234
throw err
```

You could derive a class from the `Error` class and add your own properties to it if you want something more reusable.